# Virtualbox上で仮想マシンを起動しようとするとエラーになる

Tags: virtualbox

ほとんど同様のトラブルを相談された方がいるのは承知しておりますが、表面的なエラーメッセージが同じでも解決策はどうも異なるようなので、質問させて下さい。
Virtualbox5.2.16で仮想マシンをRedHat64bitで作成して、CentOSのイメージをアタッチして起動しようとしたのですが、初回の起動の時から添付のスクリーンショットのエラーが出て起動しません。
[image: エラー画面]

[image: エラー画面2]
[image: Windowsの機能の有効化・無効化]
説明のためにスクリーンショットの画面が多くなってしまい申し訳ありません。
どのようにすれば解決するか、皆さんの知見を拝借したくご質問させて頂きます。

エラーのログファイルである、VBoxHardening.logをコピペサイトに掲載しました。
この内容から原因を推察できる方がいらっしゃればと思います。
https://pastebin.com/ecKXChUX

ATOkがエラーの原因になっているようにも見えるため、MS-IMEに切り替えて実行した際のログも添付します。
https://pastebin.com/8HGDYJr3

Comment: 追加の情報ですが、Virtualboxをインストールする前にDoker for Windowsをインストールして使用していました。Docker for Windowsのアンインストールと共に、Windowsの機能の有効化・無効化が画面からHyper-Vのチェックと、Windowsハイバーバイザープラットフォームのチェックを外しました。BIOS上で、Intel Virtualization Technologyが有効になっている事、VT-dが有効になっている事を確認しております。また、Virtualboxの再インストールなども試しました。

Comment: 解決策は役立つ情報になると思いますので、質問文に直接追記してしまうのではなく、個別の自己回答としてもらえるとベターです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。当サイトの利用経験がほとんど無かったため、助かりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

解決策が判明しましたので掲載します。
IBM Trusteer社のカスタマーサポートセンターの方からの対応です。
1）Rapport セキュリティポリシーの無効化

1.画面左下のスタートボタンまたは、キーボード上のWindows キーをクリック
　→[アルファベット T ]-[Trusteer エンドポイント保護]を辿り、
　プルダウンメニューより[Trusteer エンドポイント保護コンソール]を選択する

2.　四分割画面の右下にある[セキュリティポリシー]内より
　　ポリシーの編集　をクリックする

3.　ユーザーによる許可画面が表示されたら、
　　ゆがんだ英数字を白い四角に半角で入力し、OK を選択する

4.　次の部分を　常に使用→使用しない　へ変更する
　　・許可されない削除からTrusteer Endpoint Protection を保護する

5.　左下の[保存する]をクリックすると、
　　別で小さなウィンドウが開くのでOK ボタンで閉じる

6.　PC を再起動する（これにより変更内容が適用されます）

2）一部のRapport ファイルの無効化

1.キーボード上[Windowsキー]+[Rキー]を押下し[名前を指定して実行]を表示する
　　⇒スタートボタンの右クリックでも[名前を指定して実行]を選択できます

2.名前の空欄に次の文言を貼り付けし、[OK]をクリックする

C:\ProgramData\Trusteer\Rapport\store\exts\RapportCerberus

3.baseline（Baseline）というフォルダを開く

4.【RapportCerberus.sys】を含むファイルを全て、
　　半角アンダーバー（_）で始まるように変更する

※【.sys】で終わるファイルのみ
　　例：RapportCerberus64_59849.sys　⇒　_RapportCerberus64_59849.sys

5.上記2.で開いた　\RapportCerberus　フォルダへ戻り、
　　数字のみで構成されたフォルダを開く（フォルダが複数ある場合がございます）

6.上記4.と同じように、【RapportCerberus.sys】を含むファイルを全て、
　　半角アンダーバー（_）で始まるように変更する

※各々のフォルダが空（何も無い）の場合は、
　　　画面を閉じてPC の再起動を行ってください

上記の手順で一部のRapport ファイルの無効化する事で、Virtualboxの動作に支障を与えないように出来るようです。
ただ、この措置はVirtualboxを使用する時に行って、ネットバンキングを使用する際は元に戻すようにとのことでした。

また、本事象はTrusteer社でも認識しており、バージョンアップで対応予定とのことです。

Answer (score 4):

回答者の皆様におかれましては、様々なアドバイスをいただき大変ありがとうございます。
しかしながら、回答者の皆様から頂いたアドバイスの範囲では残念ながら解決に至らなかったため、引き続き独自に調査をし、結果解決に至りました事をご報告致します。

この現症は同様の条件が揃えば再現する問題だと考えますので、他の利用者の皆様方の問題解決の手助けとなるよう、ここに問題解決に至った経緯を記録・ご説明差し上げます。

まず、エラーログとして保存された「VBoxHardening.log」をテキストビューワーで詳細に確認し、初めて「error」の文言が出現する箇所を確かめました。

「VBoxHardening.log」上で初めて「error」の文言が出現したのは、以下の部分でした。

`43c0.2ba8: Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=5)`

このエラーは、私がスクリーンショットとして添付した一番目のものである、
「Virtualbox Error In supR3HardenedWinReSpawn」というタイトルバーのエラー画面の内容と一致します。

[image: Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=5)に対応するエラーダイアログ]

従ってこの、「Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=5)」を手がかりとして問題解決を図ることにしました。

上記のエラーをそのままGoogleで検索しても「enmWhat=5」の部分が、「enmWhat=3」のものまで検索結果に含まれてしまうため、

`Error 104 supR3HardenedWinReSpawn "(enmWhat=5)"`

というクエリーでGoogle検索をした結果、次に示すサイトが見つかりました。

[【VirtualBox】エラーで起動しなくなった（Error -104 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn!） | ノマドブロガーの歩み](http://nomad.kixas.net/?p=716)

[virtualbox.org • View topic - [Invalid] VBox Hardening and Norton Antivirus](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=88357&p=423295&hilit=Error+104+supR3HardenedWinReSpawn+enmWhat%3D5#p423295)
２番目のサイトはVirtualboxの公式フォーラムの様ですが、Googleの自動翻訳で日本語に翻訳するだけで十分意味が分かります。

私の環境では、大手銀行のネットバンキングサービスの一環としてIBMの提供している、
trusteerの「Rapport」というエンドポイントセキュリティーのツールが動作していました。
試しにこの「Rapport」をアンインストールして見たところ、問題無く仮想マシンが起動したことをご報告致します。

しかしながら、このエンドポイントセキュリティーのツールである「Rapport」をアンインストールした状態でネットバンキングを使用する事にはためらいを感じます。
ツール自体はIBMとメガバングが推奨するものですし、ネットバンキングよる不正を防ぐ目的があるはずだからです。
当面は、ネットバンキングを使う環境と、Virtualboxを使用する環境をどうに分ける事が出来ないか思案する事になりそうです。

可能であれば、「Rapport」と「Virtualbox」の間で問題解決が図られればそれが一番だと思います。

もし同じようなトラブルに遭遇されたがいらっしゃいましたら、ご参考になさって下さい。

最後に、ご回答をいただいた方々にも深く感謝致します。
本当にありがとうございましたm(__)m

Comment: >IBMの提供している、trusteerの「Rapport」
情報提供ありがとうございます。
どうしてもVirtualBoxが起動できなくて困っていましたが、ビンゴでした。
VirtualBoxは結構クリティカルなソフトみたいで、起動するまでの手続きが
結構大変でした。

Answer (score 1):

同じく**VirtualBox 5.2.16**、Window 7/Windows 10 (ホストOS、ゲストOS共に32bit版)の環境で、多少メッセージは違いますがゲストOS起動時にエラーが出るようになりました。
メッセージに出ている通り、VirtualBoxの再インストール(修復)を行うことでいったんは起動できるようになるのですが、ホストOSの再起動後(？)をきっかけにまた同じ現象が再現します。

5.2.16が問題を抱えている可能性もあるので、私はまだ試せていませんが旧バージョン(5.2.14)の利用も検討してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。旧バージョンに置き換えて試して見ましたが、全く同様のエラーでした。

Comment: 念のため、置き換え後にホストOSの再起動は実施されましたか？

Comment: ご回答、大変感謝します。IMEをMS-IMEに切り替えて、かつVirtualBoxを5.2.14に戻し、かつ再起動後に同じく試してみました。同様にエラーが出ます。エラーのログは次のURLの通りでした。https://pastebin.com/Pi1CBnyU

Answer (score 1):

以下に同じようなエラーの報告があがっていました。
この報告では、`glhp64.dll`という署名されていないDLLが利用されていたことが原因でした。

[supR3HardenedWinReSpawn VERR_INVALID_NAME on specific driver paths](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17640)

`VBoxHardening.log`の内容を確認すると原因が特定できるのではと思います。

Comment: VBoxHardening.logの内容をpastebin.comに添付しました。私自身では原因が分からないのですが、このログの内容から原因を推察できる方がいらっしゃれば知見を拝借させて頂きたいです。https://pastebin.com/ecKXChUX

Comment: `VBoxHardening.log `の1640〜1647行目をみると、ATOKの`ATOK31TIP.DLL`でエラーになっているようです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。試しにATOKかたIMEに切り替えたところエラーは改善しませんでしたが、エラーログの内容は次のように変わりました。https://pastebin.com/8HGDYJr3

Comment: @ShinichiYagi  ログを確認するとDLLのエラーはなくなっています。そのため、この状態で、@cubickさんの回答を参考に、旧バージョンを試されてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 双方へコメントするのが相応しいかわかりませんが、cubickさんのアドバイス通りに、IMEの切り替え、VirtualBoxのバージョンを5.2.14へ戻し、かつ再起動後に試しましたが、エラーは改善しませんでした。https://pastebin.com/Pi1CBnyU

Comment: @ShinichiYagi さん `VBoxHardening.log `にある`supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103`というログからググルしかないと思います。http://gintec.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/10/10/162557 とか https://qiita.com/VTRyo/items/1b7a439844f93fd3b033 などがヒットします。申し訳ないですが、同じ環境がないため、ご自身でこれらの情報から試されるしかないと思います。